# Magento 2.0 Pass custom input in phtml to controller

Tags: magento2, adminform, admin-controller

I want pass an input data from phtm file to controller. I create a js file and I can get the value of input that I want pass but how I pass this value to controller only with JavaScript (no Jquery).

phtml file:

```
<button onclick="inputQty(<?php echo $cont ?>)" id="qtyAdd2Cart" type="submit"
                 title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                 class="action tocart primary">
  <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function inputQty(id){
   id = "qty"+id;
   alert(id)
 }
```

In this moment only do an alert with id, but I can capture the value of input. I only need pass this value to controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put some code here with details?

Comment: Yes, I edit the post

Comment: Do you use in AJAX Or Page submit?

Comment: Is a button that call to controller. The module is from magento, I create a module that override their controller and create a costom js to get the input value. The problem is this value pass to controller. The module on the core imagine that use AJAX because I click in the button and load in minicart the product but the page is the same